# Run on the fly tomcat in Netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, netbeans

I'm trying to run a maven web project in Netbeans like we do in Eclipse.

I'm referring to the possibility of running the project without calling the clean/package maven goal and publishing it to the Tomcat directly.

In eclipse we chose run on server and that's it, Eclipse copy the files to the Tomcat and bam!. In netbeans it calls all that maven goals, it goes through all the test and then publish the war.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is that an issue if Netbeans calls the maven build and publishes to tomcat as long as the application runs fine?

Comment: It's a very big application, maven goals take 15 minutes to run, in a development environment this makes things very painful. I'm tied to Eclipse because of this, but I'd like to use Netbeans so I'm looking for a way to make it work like Eclipse-

Comment: Do you want the describe behaviour when you manually deploy the project? What I mean is, deploy on save functionality works as expected, doesn't it? On the other hand, do you have a Maven profile which is configured to skip tests?

Comment: I'm very new to Java web-development, but maybe that helps - I just build the project to the `webapps` folder of Tomcat, and then open the needed file in the browser like `localhost:8080/WebApp/web/qw.jsp`